# Error message facebook ads-api advertising an event with ads_management permission of the user

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-events

im having difficulties by trying to advertise an event through the facebook ads api. My facebook app has the "reate_event,manage_pages,read_stream,ads_management" permission of the user, who set up an event on facebook.

When i call the facebook ads api with creating an ad it throws me following error message:

```
[error] => stdClass Object
    (
        [type] => Exception
        [message] => The user is not an admin of the object or the object is not publicly accessible.
        [code] => 1487202
    )
```

I did try the same call with being an admin of the specific event and that worked.
Thanks for your help!
Emin

Comment: That looks like a fairly clear error to me, you can't advertise something you're not an admin of - to advertise the event you need to be an admin of the event, no?

Comment: But what is the ads_management permission for than?

Comment: It's the user granting your app access to create ads on their behalf, it doesn't let you override how Facebook's ads products work, it just lets your app create ads for a user who's given you permission to do so

Comment: Yes, but it only lets me create ads on a users behalf with his own ad account. I want to provide the service, that i create the ad for him with my ad account and invoice him later.

Comment: Then you need to contact Facebook and register as an agency and set up the ad accounts for each of your clients with invoicing and credit lines - the ads API only allows you to use the funding source or invoicing already on the account

Answer (score 0):

Ads on Facebook are always created using the context of current user, so only objects that are accessible by the current user can be promoted.

In this case, the user creating the ads does not have access to the event that is being promoted and it is not public, therefore it cannot be promoted.

It is not sufficient for your app to have access to a user's objects.

Comment: Exactly thats my problem. The owner of the object does not have an facebook ads account but wants to promote his event via our tool. Any idea how we could handle that?

Comment: Could that user not just create a Facebook ad account? Any user can have one as long as they have a credit card.